# How to use the cookies stored on a device for a headless session of chromium / edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromium

I'm trying to make use of this https://github.com/adriancs2/HTML-PDF-Edge
Specifically:

```cs
using (var p = new Process())
            {
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "msedge";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = $"--headless --user-data-dir --disable-gpu --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf=\"{filePath}\" {url}";
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
            }
```

My current issue is that when I run edge in headless mode, the cookies from my session (even with a non-headless browser open at the same time) do not translate into the headless session.
Resulting in my objective, export a bunch of HTML websites behind a simple auth, not work.

How can I "tell chromium/edge" to use the cookies stored on the PC?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'll only need to specify your profile, the session of which contains the desired cookies. I can see you've specified **--user-data-dir**. But the problem is, [the old headless mode seems to not respect the your profile](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/921).

You can use [the new headless mode](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/) which has been released recently. Just try: `--headless=new`. Then, you'll be able to find your stored cookies in your profile.

Comment: Thank you for the "new headless mode" mention.